# $(x,y+yz)=(x,y)$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Say we work on the polynomial ring $k[x,y,z]$. Set $m=(x,y,z)$ and $I=(x,y)$. My question is, is $I=(x,y+yz)$?

My first answer is no since I cannot find a way to generate $y$ from the ideal $(x,y+yz)$.

My second answer is yes. It's clear that $x,y+yz \in I$. Also, their images in $I/mI$ are $x,y$, hence generate $I/mI$. By Nakayama lemma, $(x,y+yz)=I$.

Apparently im wrong somewhere here. Thanks.

Comment: We do have Nakayama for graded rings, dont we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the fallacy in the 'second answer': the Jacobson radical of $R=k[x, y, z]$ is 0. See the (8) and (12) [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00DV).

Now back to the original question, consider the case char $k=2$. Now modulo $(z-1)$, the ideal $(x, y+yz)=(x)$ which doesn't contain $y$.

Comment: We do have Nakayama for graded rings, dont we?

Comment: Yes, there is a version here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EKB